# What framework/library compiles the smallest possible "hello world" application stand-alone executable in 2023?

Tags: command-line, node.js, typescript

I'd like to use typescript for creating simple (command-line) applications. But I can't really find a tutorial/guide/docs that show me how to create a small binary.

pkg, deno compile etc creates binaries in the 50+ MB range, which is ludacris for "hello world" command line application.

Where do I go?